# How can I check if the array of objects have same values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here my array contains  same address id but different phoneType and phonenumber.
I need some help with iterating through array,i want to get phoneType and phonenumber when adressid is same. I keep getting stuck when comparing object values in array.

```
var userdetail = [
    { name: "Steve",   adressID: "1", phoneType:"main",  phonenumber:"12222228"},
    { name: "Steve",   adressID: "1", phoneType:"fax" ,  phonenumber:"55555668"},
    { name: "Peter",   adressID: "2", phoneType:"main",  phonenumber:"67544442"},
    { name: "Elaine",  adressID: "3", phoneType:"main",  phonenumber:"87877778"},
    { name: "Elaine",  adressID: "3", phoneType:"mobile",phonenumber:"23234678"},
    { name: "Steve",   adressID: "1", phoneType:"work",  phonenumber:"42222228"},
];
```

my expected out should be

```
     {
  "name": "Steve",
  "adressID": "1",
  "phoneType": "main",
  "phonenumber": "12222228"
},
{
  "name": "Steve",
  "adressID": "1",
  "phoneType": "fax",
  "phonenumber": "55555668"
},
{
  "name": "Steve",
  "adressID": "1",
  "phoneType": "work",
  "phonenumber": "42222228"
}
```

Comment: How will the expected output look like?

Comment: Please also share your code that you have tried.

Comment: @brk i have updated my question and @ palaѕн i ll update my fiddle wht i tried

Comment: The expected output is wrong.Inside array there cannot be key and value like data unless you use an object

Comment: This question is similar to ```The train runs at 60 miles per hour and what is the age of your father```

Comment: @brk yes your out put is correct

Comment: @ Ankit Agarwal  you mean to same their is no connection between my question and output

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object where the addressID will be the key and the value of this key will be an array of objects which have this same key as the addressID

```js
var userdetail = [{
    name: "Steve",
    adressID: "1",
    phoneType: "main",
    phonenumber: "12222228"
  },
  {
    name: "Steve",
    adressID: "1",
    phoneType: "fax",
    phonenumber: "55555668"
  },
  {
    name: "Peter",
    adressID: "2",
    phoneType: "main",
    phonenumber: "67544442"
  },
  {
    name: "Elaine",
    adressID: "3",
    phoneType: "main",
    phonenumber: "87877778"
  },
  {
    name: "Elaine",
    adressID: "3",
    phoneType: "mobile",
    phonenumber: "23234678"
  },
  {
    name: "Steve",
    adressID: "1",
    phoneType: "work",
    phonenumber: "42222228"
  },
];
var result = userdetail.reduce(function(res, o) {
  res[o.adressID] || (res[o.adressID] = []); // if the adressID key doesn't exist, set it to be an array

  res[o.adressID].push(o); // push the object into the array

  return res;
}, {});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it, first groupby the array, function is taken from the SO answer, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects), then access whatever name you want, refer the below snippet!

```js
var userdetail = [{
    name: "Steve",
    adressID: "1",
    phoneType: "main",
    phonenumber: "12222228"
  },
  {
    name: "Steve",
    adressID: "1",
    phoneType: "fax",
    phonenumber: "55555668"
  },
  {
    name: "Peter",
    adressID: "2",
    phoneType: "main",
    phonenumber: "67544442"
  },
  {
    name: "Elaine",
    adressID: "3",
    phoneType: "main",
    phonenumber: "87877778"
  },
  {
    name: "Elaine",
    adressID: "3",
    phoneType: "mobile",
    phonenumber: "23234678"
  },
  {
    name: "Steve",
    adressID: "1",
    phoneType: "work",
    phonenumber: "42222228"
  },
];

var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

var data = groupBy(userdetail, 'name');
console.log(data);

//access values for steve
for (var k of data['Steve']) {
  console.log(k['phonenumber']);
  console.log(k['phoneType']);
}
```

```css
.as-console {
  height: 100%;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3558981 there is no jquery here....you can just use apply method and get the best output

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) for things like this (data wrangling)...

```
var results = _.filter(userdetail, {name: 'Steve'});
```